# How to "rotate" SPARQL results in a "loop"?

Tags: sparql

### Problem

I want to select an arbitrary subset of size n for each element of an answer.

For one specific element, like the city of Leipzig, I can solve it like this in DBpedia (http://www.dbpedia.org/sparql):

**Example Query Single Element**

```
select ?p
{
 ?p dbo:birthPlace dbr:Leipzig.
} limit 3
```

**Output Single Element**

```
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Walter_Ulbricht
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Anita_Berber
http://dbpedia.org/resource/Martin_Benno_Schmidt
```

But I want to rotate the output and do this for all (or a certain number of) cities:

**Desired Output Multiple Elements**

```
City         Person1               Person2                 Person3
dbr:Leipzig  dbr:Walter_Ulbricht       dbr:Anita_Berber    dbr:Martin_Benno_Schmidt
dbr:Bonn     dbr:Anton_Schumacher      dbr:Hermann_Wallich dbr:Fritz_Simrock
dbr:Paris    dbr:Adrien-Marie_Legendre dbr:André_Malraux   dbr:Anselme_Payen
...
```

I tried to solve this with the following query:

```
SELECT ?city SAMPLE(?p1) SAMPLE(?p2) SAMPLE(?p3)
{
 ?city ^dbo:birthPlace ?p1,?p2,?p3.
 ?city a dbo:City.

 FILTER(?p1<?p2&&?p2<?p3) # prevent permutations and duplicates

} GROUP BY ?city # only one line per city
LIMIT 10
```

However I am not sure if this is the best solution and I have a few questions:

- With larger n this way of writing the query gets cumbersome, is there a more elegant option (e.g. using subqueries)?
- Does this query give me all the results I want, i.e. does it sample the whole row, or does it lose results by sampling each variable seperately and then skipping valid solutions?
- If it does return all the results I would have gotten by repeating single element queries, does it have the same efficiency or does it run through a large number of permutations before filtering them out? If it is not, is there a way to write it more efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a reasonably elegant and efficient solution:

1. In a subquery, use `GROUP BY` with the `group_concat` aggregate to merge the URIs for all people of one city into one long string.
2. Outside of the subquery, use string functions to break apart the long string and take the first n items.

Done here for the first 100 cities with five people per city:

```
SELECT ?c ?p1 ?p2 ?p3 ?p4 ?p5 {
    {
        SELECT ?c (group_concat(?p; separator=' ') AS ?list1) {
            {
                SELECT ?c { ?c a dbo:City } LIMIT 100
            }
            OPTIONAL { ?p dbo:birthPlace ?c }
        }
        GROUP BY ?c
    }
    BIND (if(?list1, strAfter(?list1, ' '), undef) AS ?list2)
    BIND (if(?list2, strAfter(?list2, ' '), undef) AS ?list3)
    BIND (if(?list3, strAfter(?list3, ' '), undef) AS ?list4)
    BIND (if(?list4, strAfter(?list4, ' '), undef) AS ?list5)

    BIND (if(?list1, if(contains(?list1, ' '), IRI(strBefore(?list1, ' ')), IRI(?list1)), undef) AS ?p1)
    BIND (if(?list2, if(contains(?list2, ' '), IRI(strBefore(?list2, ' ')), IRI(?list2)), undef) AS ?p2)
    BIND (if(?list3, if(contains(?list3, ' '), IRI(strBefore(?list3, ' ')), IRI(?list3)), undef) AS ?p3)
    BIND (if(?list4, if(contains(?list4, ' '), IRI(strBefore(?list4, ' ')), IRI(?list4)), undef) AS ?p4)
    BIND (if(?list5, if(contains(?list5, ' '), IRI(strBefore(?list5, ' ')), IRI(?list5)), undef) AS ?p5)
}
```

Comment: Wow, I never would have thought about this approach, thanks!

Comment: My apologies, but there was a problem in my answer, and correcting it makes it slightly less elegant. I was confused about `strBefore(x, ' ')`. I thought if `' '` is not found, it would return `x`. But it actually returns an empty string. I fixed it now by adding another `if` to all the person lines (and reordered the lines for clarity).